# Is the site wrong about an ethical hacking question or am I?

Tags: virus, backdoor

[image]

Can you let me know if this site is crazy? or am I?

Comment: Bug in the website, that definition suits only to "virus".

Comment: Thanks Mirsad, I have quite a few screenshots where the training sites are wrong. It's very dissapointing and frustrating for people who are trying to learn or pass an exam. Even my paid course contradicts itself throughout the modules, that's why I also search elsewhere. How I'm going to pass, I don't know.

Comment: The best way to handle all the errors and mistakes in both the free and paid, official exam prep questions, is not to memorize the answers, but know ***why*** every single one of your answers is correct. Then, you can handle mistakes on their end. Treat every proposed answer from them as only a suggestion or an opinion. Then verify on your own. It will make you a stronger test taker (and more knowledgeable).

Comment: In case it may be useful to you: I've just written [a post](https://www.whitewinterwolf.com/posts/2017/10/04/ec-council-ceh-certification-review/) with a review and few advices for the CEH exam. Don't hesitate to provide me any feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right and the website is wrong.

I know it's frustrating but I think that anyone who went through a certification also went through the same frustration ;).

Sometimes, the issue is not even in the training program but in the certification organism itself who do not check his own questions enough (question quality varies greatly from one organism to another). Training programs then only reflect this situation by using older official questions and answers.

Instead, take the fact that you have now enough knowledge and confidence to challenge such answers as a good sign of your level. At the end, you don't need 100% good answers. As long as you have enough knowledge, you should be able to pass despite odd, malformed and wrong questions.

Comment: Thank you, your answer encouraged me to be more confident, I went to my exam and passed first time :)

Comment: @LukeDobner: Congratulations :) , I'm glad if my answer helped you!

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments of the question the correct answer is in fact `virus`.

This is a common issue of using online (and free) test banks. The question/answer database is not reviewed for errors. I have yet to find a reasonably priced, error-free exam bank for Network Security exams.

What I recommend you do is **use the resources included with and inside physical books**. The book itself will quite likely contain error-free exam test questions, and some additional ones on a CD. This route will be more pricey, but certainly worth the added costs.

This is how I studied for my CompTIA Security+ CE exam, and will be continuing with my CompTIA CASP exam.

Comment: I wouldn't blindly accept test questions as being correct just because they're in a physical book - I've seen similar errors in books, and even in actual exam papers.